# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los enlaces <a> de cualquier párrafo <p> usando DOM e imprimirlos en ótro párrafo con id=info?

Tags: javascript

Soy estudiante de desarrollo web. El objetivo de esta lección es aprender a usar *innerHTML*, para eso me pusieron éste ejercicio y publico ésta pregunta porque eh buscado exhaustivamente en internet pero nadie ah hecho un ejemplo sobre un caso así.

> Dado un archivo HTML ¿Cómo puedo obtener los enlaces `<a>` del tercer o cualquier párrafo `<p>` usando DOM e imprimirlos en otro párrafo con `id=info`?

No quisiera que me respondan el ejercicio porque el objetivo es aprender y llegar a la solución yo sola. Ya leí todo sobre *appendChild*, *createElement*, *innerHTML* y todos los métodos relacionados con eso, aún así hay algo que no estoy entendiendo.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: Probablemente quieras consultar [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API) e intentar algo tu misma antes de querer ver una solución.

Comment: Revisa [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: Dices que muestras tu código, pero éste no está... revisa tu pregunta.

Comment: track3r, había adjuntado una pequeña imagen y ahora veo que no está, quizás un administrador la sacó.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que hace uso de:

- [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) para obtener el elemento con id "datos", que es en el que se realizará la publicación final de lo encontrado, que dejo almacenado en la variable `datos`.
- Una variable llamada `texto` en la que se irá guardando los valores encontrados para finalmente añadirlos al elemento `datos`.
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para obtener todos los divs del documento.
- Luego utiliza el índice `[1]` sobre esta lista, para obtener el segundo elemento, que es el segundo div, que se almacena en la variable `segundo`. (Debes tener presente que en arreglos y listas, el primer elemento tiene el índice `[0]`, el segundo `[1]` y así sucesivamente).
- Vuelvo a utilizar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), esta vez sobre el mencionado segundo elemento, para obtener todos los anchors (etiquetas `<a>`) contenidos en él.
- Sobre la lista retornada utilizo la función [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para iterar por los elementos de la misma.
- A `forEach` le paso una función de flecha ([`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).
- En dicha función voy concatenando el anchor a la variable `texto`, que se ha inicializado previamente.
- Finalmente utilizo la propiedad [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) para mostrar en la página el resultado de la búsqueda.

```js
const datos = document.getElementById("datos");
const segundo = document.querySelectorAll("div")[1];
let texto = "los anchors encontrados son estos:<br>";
segundo.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((el) => {
  texto += el + "<br>"
});
datos.innerHTML = texto;
```

```html
<div>uno <a href="#uno">lleva a uno</a> y a <a href="https://google.com">google</a></div>
<div>dos <a href="#dos">lleva a dos</a> y a <a href="https://yahoo.com">yahoo</a></div>
<div>tres <a href="#tres">lleva a tres y a <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a></a></div>
<div>cuatro <a href="#cuatro">lleva a cuatro</a> y a <a href="https://google.com">google</a></div>
<div>cinco <a href="#cinco">lleva a cinco</a> y a <a href="https://yahoo.com">yahoo</a></div>

<p id="datos">aquí van los datos, cuando se encuentren</p>
```

Si estudias el código con atención, estoy seguro que podrás extraer todo lo que necesitas para realizar la tarea con los elementos de la misma. Dejé bastantes ligas a la documentación oficial (en inglés), que te puede ayudar a aclarar la forma de uso de las diferentes funciones y propiedades de las que voy tirando.

Comment: probablemente, te "regalen" varios negativos (el OP no muestra código), se que no compensa... pero tienes mi upvote y admiración!!

Comment: Gracias @Marce, yo veo una pregunta sencilla, una persona que necesita un cable para arrancar y uso eso como pretexto para generar contenido que espero sea de valor y de ayuda a otros que estén iniciando en el futuro. Ya la comunidad verá como votar según su criterio. Gracias por el comentario. Un saludo.

Comment: Me alegra que haya personas como tu en este sitio!!!

Comment: Gracias jachguate, fue de gran ayuda y pude resolver el ejercicio además de aprender un poco mas.